# Cron stopped working after setting up multi store on Magento2

Tags: magento2, multistore, cron, crontab

On Magento2 with the following setting on cPanel, cronjob was working.

- /usr/local/bin/php /home/mystore/bin/magento cron:run |
  grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >>
  /home/mystore/var/log/magento.cron.log
- /usr/local/bin/php /home/mystore/update/cron.php >> /home/mystore/var/log/update.cron.log
- /usr/local/bin/php /home/mystore/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/mystore/var/log/setup.cron.log

However, once I have set up multi store, it stopped. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to run `php bin/magento cron:run`

Comment: with SSH? or in cronjob setting of cPanel?

Comment: Using SSH please

Comment: it says "Ran jobs by schedule."

Comment: I upgraded to 2.1.3 and somehow it is working now